# Error : occurred configuring project

Tags: android, github

I get this error when I try to build my Telegram project :

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':TMessagesProj'.
>   executing external native build for ndkBuild C:\Users\M\Desktop\apps\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk

I use telegram surce code from : https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram
URL of Android.mk is : https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/jni/Android.mk

Answer (score 0):

Before a few days ago I also faced the same issue. 
I added

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
```

in `.Gradel` file above

```
buildTypes{}
```

Comment: did you found the solution?